# How to pass a shape that is dependent on a placeholder to tf.get_variable()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I met this error when running a `tf.graph`:

> You can only pass an initializer function that expects no arguments to its callable when the shape is not fully defined.

I am able to reproduce the err:

```
m = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=m.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(v))
```

In my usecase, I need a `placeholder` that will dynamically changed when the program is running, and the shape of variable `v` has to depend on the shape of the placeholder.

I have been googled extensively and got none answers, any one could help? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot do that. Variable shapes must be fully known in advance, they cannot change depending on the shape of another tensor.

Comment: Well, actually, you can pass `validate_shape=False` and it will not complain, although it is not a very extended practice. As the documentation for [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) states, in that case the initializer must be a tensor and not an initializer object. But it will not make the shape of the variable change with every input, it will take the shape of the given tensor on initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How to resolve the problem? I think this can be a general use case of tensor flow, that a variable depends on a placeholder that set by a user on the fly

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure this actually makes much sense... The point of having a variable is to have a value that you can keep between different calls to `run`... so how would that work if the shape of the variable changes? What exactly is the reason why you want to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `shape=m.shape`. We can get the shape of a Placeholder only after executing it. Below code runs without any error.

```
m = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    m_val = sess.run(m, feed_dict={m:[[2,3], [3,2]]})
    v = tf.get_variable(name = "v", shape= m_val.shape)
```